# Track Complete flow, Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

As a part of tracking full flow, do anyone have idea how to track full flow:

*Let us take an below example:*

- Customer clicks on A button (“Operation A” starts).
- Slide In Opens (With Some ID)
- Customer completes operation A
- Customer gets the receipt page.

*So, I want to check,*

- How many completes the flow?
- How many drops in between?
- How much time it takes for user to complete the flow?

**I tried it with following approach:**

- create a custom javascript that will check if "SlideIn" by ID is visible or not.
- Then check IDs on SlideIn and receipt page.

Now, how to check success and failures and time to operation

Comment: As this isn't specifically related to coding, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. You should post this to Webmasters instead.

Comment: You should just  fire the events without any regard to global state, and then filter it on GA. I kinda agree with Nyuen, since this is more of a GA configuration question.

Comment: Can't you just set up a goal flow (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2520139?hl=en) and push "time between action A and action B" (accumulative, need be) as a custom metric?